# stop wordpress revision and autosave to page

Tags: wordpress, revision

Wordpress revision and autosave is keeping reverting my changes to a wordpress page. No matter how many changes I make always reverting to that point.

Is there some solution to stop doing that but not to disable revision to all site.

Comment: increase autosave time

Comment: It is short term solution but it will do same thing again after some period.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To **Disable Autosave** put the code below in your functions.php.

```
function disableAutoSave(){
     wp_deregister_script('autosave');
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'disableAutoSave' );
```

To **Disable Post Revisions** put the code below in your wp-config.php file.

```
define( 'WP_POST_REVISIONS', false ); // no revisions
```

**Note: Using the above code will disable the Autosave and/or Post Revisions 
    throughout the site.**

Comment: How to stop revisions committed by contributor? @golchha21

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct code should be as above code throws notification messages.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'disable_autosave' );
function disable_autosave() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'autosave' );
}
```